# Нужно,используя python,отправить данные на сайт и сохранить их в базу данных

Tags: php, html, mysql, python, sql

Необходимо заполнить форму на сайте. Затем полученные данные записать в таблицу в базу данных.

Форма:

```
<form action="" method="post">

        <label>Логин</label>
        <input name="login" id="login" type="text"><br/>
        <label>Пароль</label>
        <input name="password" id="password" type="password"><br/>
</form>
```

php:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

$login = $_POST["login"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$mysqli = new mysqli ("url.ru","user","password","base");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `auth`(`login`,`password`) VALUES ($login,$password)");

$mysqli->close();}
```

Пытался использовать requests и grab:

```
#requests
import requests
s = requests.session()
values = {'login':'test', 'password':'test'}
url = 'url.ru'
s.post(url, data=values)

#grab
from grab import Grab
g = Grab()
g.go('url.ru')
g.set_input('login','test')
g.set_input('password','test')
```

Форма заполнялась(это можно увидеть если запрос заключить в переменную), но в таблицу данные не записывались. Почему?

p.s. Когда форма заполняется через python(grab),php просто игнорирует строки с запросами к базе данных, а весь остальной код нормально выполняется. **Почему?**

p.s.s php не выполняет именно эту строку,остальное все работает(в том числе и остальные запросы к базе):

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `auth`(`login`,`password`) VALUES ($login,$password)");
```

Comment: результат запроса проверяли?

Comment: Выдает страницу с формой(если выводить на страницу введенное значение с формы,то его видно в результате запроса, значит почему-то не проводится именно запрос к базе данных)

Comment: Мне кажется  по умолчанию у вас GET-запрос, а php ждет POST.

Comment: Пробовал в html/php выставлять get запрос, пробовал прямо указывать post запрос в python. Все равно не получается

Comment: http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю почему, но все заработало когда я поместил переменные в этом запросе в двойные кавычки:`$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO`auth`(`login`,`password`) VALUES ($login,$password)");`

То есть получилось так:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `auth`(`login`,`password`) VALUES (\"$login\",\"$password\")");
```

Если кто-то мне объяснит почему нужно было сделать именно так, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать примерно так, у меня работает: $db ->query("INSERT INTO user (login, password, email, phone) VALUES ('$login', '$password','$email', '$phone')");